# MySQL's JSON_TABLE gives skewed results

Tags: mysql, json

In the below MySQL query, I'm trying to extract JSON values - I have 3 JSON arrays with the same amount of values:

```
{
  "0": "",
  "faults": [
    "Damaged Load Cell Housing",
    "Damaged Top Plate"
  ],
  "resolutions": [
    "Replaced Load Cell Rubber(s)",
    "Replaced Load Cell Screw(s)"
  ],
  "uspn": [
    "",
    "424214"
  ]
}
```

I'd like to display each value from an array next to each other in one row in separate columns.
Here's my query:

```
SELECT * FROM json_table(
    '{"0":"","faults":["Damaged Metal Tray","Failed Max Load","Damaged Hood Assembly","No Power \/ Dead Control Board"],"resolutions":["Replaced Metal Tray","Replaced CAL Cover","Replaced Load Cell Housing","Replaced Control Board"],"kg":["","7.509","",""],"uspn":["110432","","214421",""],"pcb_replaced":"1","notes":""}',
    '$' columns  (
        NESTED PATH '$.faults[*]' COLUMNS (nid_1 FOR ORDINALITY, Fault TEXT PATH '$'),
        NESTED PATH '$.resolutions[*]' COLUMNS (nid_2 FOR ORDINALITY, Resolution TEXT PATH '$'),
        NESTED PATH '$.uspn[*]' COLUMNS (nid_3 FOR ORDINALITY, USPN TEXT PATH '$')
    )
) j;
```

which gives me this result:

```
| nid_1 | Fault                         | nid_2 | Resolution                 | nid_3 | USPN   |
| ----- | ----------------------------- | ----- | -------------------------- | ----- | ------ |
| 1     | Damaged Metal Tray            | NULL  | NULL                       | NULL  | NULL   |
| 2     | Failed Max Load               | NULL  | NULL                       | NULL  | NULL   |
| 3     | Damaged Hood Assembly         | NULL  | NULL                       | NULL  | NULL   |
| 4     | No Power / Dead Control Board | NULL  | NULL                       | NULL  | NULL   |
| NULL  | NULL                          | 1     | Replaced Metal Tray        | NULL  | NULL   |
| NULL  | NULL                          | 2     | Replaced CAL Cover         | NULL  | NULL   |
| NULL  | NULL                          | 3     | Replaced Load Cell Housing | NULL  | NULL   |
| NULL  | NULL                          | 4     | Replaced Control Board     | NULL  | NULL   |
| NULL  | NULL                          | NULL  | NULL                       | 1     | 110432 |
| NULL  | NULL                          | NULL  | NULL                       | 2     |        |
| NULL  | NULL                          | NULL  | NULL                       | 3     | 214421 |
| NULL  | NULL                          | NULL  | NULL                       | 4     |        |
```

The above gives me skewed results which I understand why are they happening as each nested path gives me separate results and shows NULL when there's no match and creates a separate line, but cannot figure out the way how to display them right. I tried playing with JOIN which gives me same results and I can't get them to align properly.

I would like the below result without the NULL values and with each value being next to each other in columns and in one row:

```
| nid_1 | Fault                         | nid_2 | Resolution                 | nid_3 | USPN   |
| ----- | ----------------------------- | ----- | -------------------------- | ----- | ------ |
| 1     | Damaged Metal Tray            | 1     | Replaced Metal Tray        | 1     | 110432 |
| 2     | Failed Max Load               | 2     | Replaced CAL Cover         | 2     |        |
| 3     | Damaged Hood Assembly         | 3     | Replaced Metal Tray        | 3     | 214421 |
| 4     | No Power / Dead Control Board | 4     | Replaced Control Board     | 4     |        |
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Use separate queries for each `nid_X` and then join them.

Answer (score 2):

How about a join?

```
select * from
json_table(json, '$.faults[*]' columns(id for ordinality, fault text path '$') faults
join
json_table(json, '$.resolutions[*]' columns(id for ordinality, resolution text path '$') resolutions
on faults.id=resolutions.id
join
json_table(json, '$.uspn[*]' columns (id for ordinality, uspn text path '$') uspn
on faults.id=uspn.id
```

Comment: Massive thanks, I was previoulsy playing with JOIN and was thinking there must be a way to do it, but I guess I didn't understood the ON clause correctly. :)